# Wikipedia Linked Data Fragments endpoint fails

Tags: sparql, wikidata

I am trying to get alternative names of given names in WikiData with the following simple query:

```
PREFIX ps: <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/direct/> 
PREFIX wd: <http://www.wikidata.org/entity/> 
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> 
CONSTRUCT {?s rdfs:label ?o} 
WHERE { ?s ps:P31 wd:Q202444. ?s rdfs:label ?o} 
LIMIT 1000
```

Initially, the query was much more complex, but I was getting time-outs on the public WikiData SPARQL endpoint. I decided to use [Linked Data Fragments](https://linkeddatafragments.org/) to offload some filtering from the server to the client.

```
$comunica-sparql "https://query.wikidata.org/bigdata/ldf" -f query > given_names.n3

Could not retrieve https://query.wikidata.org/bigdata/ldf?subject=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.wikidata.org%2Fentity%2FQ21147790&predicate=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23label&page=3 (500: unknown error)
```

(where `query` is a file with the SPARQL query shown above). Unfortunately, the client tries to get output from the 3rd page, I am getting the error. Following the link in fact returns HTTP 500 error with

[image]

The link points to the 3rd page. It works if you try to go to the [second page](https://query.wikidata.org/bigdata/ldf?subject=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.wikidata.org%2Fentity%2FQ21147790&predicate=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23label&page=2).
 
Is this a bug or a limitation of a service?

Comment: what is the purpose of the LDF request? getting the labels in all languages of the given entity?

Comment: @UninformedUser Getting labels and other properties of instances of a certain class. I've started with labels to see if LDR approach can help in my case. The WikiData team accepted it as a bug.

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely a bug; the server does not fulfill the Triple Pattern Fragments specification if pagination does not work.

Comment: Thank you. I've reported the issue to wikidata mailing list: https://lists.wikimedia.org/pipermail/wikidata/2020-December/014421.html